# Cloudberry Linux: How to check whether a scheduled backup is successful or not

Tags: linux, centos, backup, cloudberry

I have installed Cloudberry in Centos. Is there any way to check whether a scheduled backup is successful? Does it maintain any history like windows version of Cloudberry, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't know what the product is but typically you can at least check the exit code for success or failure

Comment: @HBruijn: It's a scheduled backup; So i would never know whether it ran and that's what i wanted to find out and if it ran is it successful or not

Answer (score 2):

As strange as this may seem the [documentation](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup/cmd-linux.aspx) appears to contain the answer to your question.

> -notification - specify to receive notification email when backup fails (errorOnly) or in all cases (on). Possible values: errorOnly (default) |on.

Comment: +1 for the novel idea of actually reading the documentation :P

Comment: Yep. I am aware of this. But I am more interested in logging process, and that's my query as well.